# How to pass javascript array to spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

How to send array to spring rest? I tried the following but didn't work

javascript:

```
function postTopic(){
    self.data.blogTopicsArr.push({
        options: {
            "title": self.title.value,
            "details": self.topicDetails.value,
            "username": "Guest user",
            "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
            "day_posted": new Date().toLocaleString()
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/new_topic",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(self.data.blogTopicsArr),
        success: function (res) {
        },
        error: function (err) {
        }
    });
}
```

Topic Bean class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class TopicBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "details")
    private String details;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "userImage")
    private String userImage;
    @Column(name = "day_posted")
    private Date day_posted;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Spring rest:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/new_topic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity new_topic(@RequestBody List[] topics) throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("success", "topic added");
    return new ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I get error: `{"statusCode":400,"body":{"timestamp":1484506636823,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity seconds47.restAPI.Topics.new_topic(java.util.List[]) throws java.lang.Exception","path":"/new_topic"}}}`

How do I solve this?

Update: added topic bean class above with fields I am using in that class

Comment: Start by debugging the interaction in the middle. The browser console will show you exactly what the HTTP request looks like. Does it match what you expected? Also, you're getting a warning about a raw type on `List`--pay attention to it, and tell Spring what sorts of objects you expect in the list. Finally, from a REST perspective, you should generally be posting (1) a single object to be created (2) to the `/topics` URL directly.

Comment: The List[] argument is probably causing an error....shouldn't it be List<Topic> or List<HashMap> ?

Comment: @dev8080 I tried `(@RequestBody List<TopicBean> topics)` but didn't work. Same error

Comment: It could be you are using JSON.stringify on the client side and need to parse the String on the server ?

Comment: JSON.stringify in the client is OK, this serializes the object sended to server. The server with the RequestBody annotation will deserialize it, but the type of object after the annotation must have the same members (type and name) as the object sended from the client.

Comment: Which puts me on my original guess, the expected type of the request body; it should be List<TopicBean> or in the absence of any explicit structure, List<HashMap<String, Object>>....

Comment: @kittu Check my answer ... you need to have a single field 'options' in your TopicBean and that field itself will have all your title,etc. attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
function postTopic(){

    var topic = {
        "title": self.title.value,
        "details": self.topicDetails.value,
        "username": "Guest user",
        "userImage": "assets/img/spiritual-icon4.png",
        "day_posted": new Date().toLocaleString()
    };


$.ajax({
    url: "/new_topic",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: topic,
    success: function (res) {
    },
    error: function (err) {
    }
});
}



@RequestMapping(path = "/new_topic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity new_topic(@RequestBody TopicBean topic) throws Exception {

    //... do whatever with the new topic 

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("success", "topic added");
    return new ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

topic and TopicBean must have the same members and must be of same type.

Comment: Exactly, problem is that the mate is sending a serialized application/json body payload which Spring is trying to deserialize in a Java object with the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/new_topic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity new_topic(@RequestBody List<HashMap<String, Object>> topics) throws Exception
```

And print out any input from *topics*. If you do get any values, you need to replace it with

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/new_topic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity new_topic(@RequestBody List<Topic> topics) throws Exception
```

with the relevant structure of the Topic class.

```
public class Topic{

    OptionsBean options;
    ...
    //getters and setters
    ...
    }

public class OptionsBean{

            String title;
            String details;
            String username;
            String userImage;
            String day_posted;

            ...
            //getters and setters
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Added the bean class I'm using to question

Comment: @jonhid added the bean class

Comment: @jonhid Check above.

Comment: OptionsBean is a nested class inside topicBean class??

Comment: So I just Autowire OptjonsBean into Topic class??

Comment: Yes, OptionBean is a field inside topicBean, to better match your js object that is passed via ajax.  No need to autowire here...just use this structure in place of your TopicBean.